# Dynamics ax 2012 deploy to ep not found

Tags: deployment, microsoft-dynamics, ax

i want to deploy a form created in Dynamics AX to EP(SharePoint) .i added this form to Menu Items but i didn't have the command "Deploy to EP".i didn' found it.
I think i didn't missed any step.Any help please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the template of the form? try changing the template to listpage and try again.